# Risks of @ID in @MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, uuid

Actually, i want to change the entity id from Type Long to the UUID.
All my entites have a MappedSuperclass. To save time, I wanted to add the new solution into the MappedSuperclass object and remove the old solution from the specific entities.

Is this a good practice or is it associated with risks?

> old solution

```
@Entity
public class CustomObject extends DomainObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
}
```

> new solution

```
   @MappedSuperclass
   public class DomainObject {

    @Id     
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @Type(type="pg-uuid")   
    @Column(name = "ID")    
    private UUID id;

   }
```

Comment: We're using ids in our mapped superclasses as well and didn't have any problems so far. In your case there _might_ be a risk if there are already existing entities: you're changing the type and id generation so any existing ids would have to be converted etc.

Comment: Thanks, i will change any existing ids after i rewrite the entity class. What if the CustomObject have an @ID declared too ? If someone mdae a typo and forgot the MappedSuperclass Object ID ?

Comment: You mean what if the entity declares `id` when then mapped superclass does it already? I'm not entirely sure but I'd assume Hibernate would complain or any developer tests would fail.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will test it on my own.